# Customize django render_comment_form fields

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-comments

(using django.contrib.comments)

When placing :

```
{% load comments %}
{% render_comment_form for event %}
```

into the template. It renders a form with a: `Name`, `email`, `url` and `comment` field.

Is there a way to just have the `comment` field appear, and have the other fields hidden while still posting data? Or should I just recreate the form myself?

Thank you in advance for you suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the attribute `is_hidden` to a field of the comments form and give it the value `True`. In that case only the value of the field will be printed but I'm not sure this is what you want.

But fortunately you can modify the form yourself. The code searches for a template at the following locations:

```
template_search_list = [
    "comments/%s/%s/form.html" % (ctype.app_label, ctype.model),
    "comments/%s/form.html" % ctype.app_label,
    "comments/form.html"
]
```

You can view the current contents of `form.html` [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/comments/templates/comments/form.html) and the code of the `render_comments_form` template tag [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/comments/templatetags/comments.py)).

If you want to modify the form for the whole website then you can create your own version of `comments/form.html` but you can also create a `form.htm` for a particular Django app or even a particular model of a Django app. In that form template you can customize which fields are displayed and which ones are hidden.

Answer (score 0):

just add this line in your form.html page:-

```
{% if field.name != "name" and field.name != "email" and field.name != "url" %}
```

u'll need to add it like this:-

```
{% if field.is_hidden %}
<div>{{ field }}</div>
{% else %}
{% if field.name != "name" and field.name != "email" and field.name != "url" %}
{% if field.errors %}{{ field.errors }}{% endif %}
```

...it worked for me...no need to do anythng else..i just wanted the comment box and nothin else!!!!